# Derivative of gradient of norm squared

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, vector-analysis

Consider $$A[u] = \int_{\Omega} 0.5| \nabla u(x)|^2 dx$$ for some function $u$

I want to compute $\frac{d}{ds} A[u +sv] = \frac{d}{ds} \int_{\Omega} 0.5| \nabla (u(x)+ s v(x))|^2 dx  $

I cannot figure out, why the result should be $\int_{\Omega}  \nabla u(x)\nabla v(x) dx$

Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Should that be the dot-product of $\nabla u$ and $\nabla v$?

Comment: Yeah it should be

Comment: Also, could you be missing a factor of $2$?

Comment: I addded a factor of 0.5

Comment: I get the following: 
$$
\frac{d}{ds} \int_{\Omega}|\nabla (u(x) + sv(x))|^2 dx = \\
\int_{\Omega}\frac{d}{ds} |\nabla u(x) + s \nabla v(x)|^2 dx =\\
\int_{\Omega}\frac{d}{ds} (|\nabla u(x)|^2 + s^2|\nabla v(x)|^2 + 2s\nabla u(x)^T \nabla v(x)) dx =\\
2 \int_\Omega [s|\nabla v(x)|^2 + \nabla u(x)^T \nabla v(x)]dx.
$$
Perhaps I'm missing some context, but the $s$ term seems to have disappeared from the integral. Maybe you're meant to evaluate the derivative at $s = 0$.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah I overread the passage that I want to evaluate at $s=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key step seems to be an initial application of the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule). We have
$$
\frac{d}{ds} \int_{\Omega}|\nabla (u(x) + sv(x))|^2 dx = \\
\int_{\Omega}\frac{d}{ds} |\nabla u(x) + s \nabla v(x)|^2 dx =\\
\int_{\Omega}\frac{d}{ds} (|\nabla u(x)|^2 + s^2|\nabla v(x)|^2 + 2s\nabla u(x)^T \nabla v(x)) dx =\\
2 \int_\Omega [s|\nabla v(x)|^2 + \nabla u(x)^T \nabla v(x)]dx.
$$
Evaluating this at $s = 0$ gives you the desired result.